# How to make a button react on the value of a textarea. Javascript

Tags: javascript, events, textarea

Im trying to make the button react on what the textarea's value.
btn represents the button, txt represents the textarea and box is the div element i want to manipulate.

```
let btn = document.getElementById("funbtn");
let txt = document.getElementById("funtxt");
let box = document.getElementById("funobject");

function answer() {
    if (txt.value === "rotate") {
        let rotate-deg = prompt("How many degrees do you wanna rotate?");
        box.setAttribute("style", "transition: 1000ms ease-in;";
        box.setAttribute("style", "transform: rotate("rotate-deg"deg);";

    }
}


btn.onclick = answer()
```

Comment: `rotate-deg` is invalid syntax, use `rotateDeg`

Comment: Correct the typos: "transform: rotate("+rotate-deg+"deg);

Comment: @jeff Even that is incorrect with `rotate-deg`

Comment: oooppps - corection: change rotate-deg to rotateDeg then change: "transform: rotate("+rotateDeg+"deg);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out!

Instead of adding a eventlistener on a button, it had to be a div element, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You got some small errors in your code.

1. `rotate-deg` is not a valid syntax for a variable in javascript.
2. you should combine the styles into one `.setAttribute`-call or work with the `.style`-properties.
3. Some quotes where wrong when using javascript-variables inside the style. Also bracket was not closed correctly.

Here is a corrected version:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("funbtn");
const txt = document.getElementById("funtxt");
const box = document.getElementById("funobject");

function answer() {
  if (txt.value === "rotate") {
    let rotateAngle = prompt("How many degrees do you wanna rotate?");
    box.setAttribute("style", "transition: 1000ms ease-in; transform: rotate(" + rotateAngle + "deg);");
  }
}
btn.addEventListener("click", answer);
```

```css
#funobject {
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<input tape="text" id="funtxt">
<button id="funbtn">Action</button>
<div id="funobject"></div>
```

Comment: I tried testing it but the same errors came up. It doesn't reconize the variables... When i write the exact same lines in the console, it works...

Answer (score 0):

this with jquery!

```js
var btn= $("#funbtn");
var txt = $("#funtxt");
var obj = $("#funobject")
btn.on('click',function(){
const val = $.trim(txt.val());
if(val==="rotate"){
obj.css("transform","rotate(180deg)")
}
});
```

```css
#funobject{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
  transition: all 5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="funtxt">
  
</textarea>
<button id="funbtn">
submit
</button>
<div id="funobject">

</div>
```